# Tengo realizado el código de PHP para sumar stock, pero como hago para que el EditTex no me muestre el dato extraido

Tags: php, android-studio

Tengo creado el código `PHP` para sumar stock de un producto que ya esta registrado solo quiero cambiar la fecha y stock, y no puedo volver registrar el mismo producto porque se crea la duplicidad en ese aspecto ya lo tengo resuelto, la cuestión es cuando llamo para modificar pero no quiero que se muestre el dato extraído, hay alguna manera de ocultar el dato de contenido en el XML, o se podría implementar de alguna otra forma, he buscado información sobre este tema pero no he podido encontrar una fuente oficial.

**sumaStock**

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");

  $codigo = $_POST["codigoViveres"];
  $fechaRegis = $_POST["fechaRegistro"];
  $stock = $_POST["stock"];


   $sqlsuma = "UPDATE t_viveres SET fechaRegistro = '$fechaRegis',stock = stock +'$stock' WHERE  codigoViveres = '$codigo'";
$result = $mysql->query($sqlsuma);

  if ($result) {
    echo "1";
 } else {
    echo "2";
 }

 $mysql->close();

 ?>
```

**XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com /apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Sumar_stock"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Código de producto"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blancogris"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200"
            android:enabled="false">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/codigo_sumaStock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Fecha de ingreso"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blancogris"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/stock_fecha_ingreso"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Stock"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blancogris"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/stock_viveres"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_regisNuevo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            android:text="REGISTRAR"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:onClick="Btn_regisNuevo"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>
     </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la imagen, cual es el dato que no quieres mostrar?

Comment: @Elenasys el de los dos campos de fecha y stock, ahí si me funciona bien, pero no seria buena idea de que el usuario tenga que borrar esos datos para poder ingresar nuevos datos, ya que tengo otro formulario donde ahí si es para modificar todo los datos.

Comment: Quieres que se eliminen los valores automáticamente cuando quieres modificar? Donde se modifica? con un botón?

Comment: @Elenasys si pero que no se eliminen o se oculten.

Comment: Sino querés que se nuestra simplemente carga el layout sin los datos extraídos del php.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo muchas gracias me sirvió tu respuesta.

Comment: @Miguel agrega como cargas en el layout los datos.